# Why do I have a muliply defined ofstream object?

Tags: c++, c++14

gcc 6.4.0
Netbeans 8.2
cygwin64

I don't know how to fix a multiply defined symbol problem. My include file has guards and there are no other symbols with the same name. The linker shows that the symbol, testoutput, is multiply defined. Whatever name I use in the declaration 'ofstream ' comes back multiply defined. I can avoid the issue by creating a stringstream variable and passing to to a output function but that seems like a really poor idea. Can I pass an i/o variable around?

Test code and linker output included:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
# include <fstream>

   using namespace std;
   ofstream testout;

#endif  /* COMMON_H */


#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
# include "Common.h"
class myClass {
public:
   void outStuff();
};

#endif /* FILE_H */

# include "File.h"
# include "Common.h"

void myClass::outStuff() {
   testout << "another thing" << endl;
};

# include "Common.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   testout.open("test.out");
   testout << "out" << endl;
}
```

======================== UUILD ==============================
    CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 255ms)
    cd 'C:\home\skidmarks\Projects\Test\Test'
    c:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory '/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/Test/Test'
    "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/test.exe
    make[2]: Entering directory '/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/Test/Test'
    mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows
    rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/File.o.d"
    g++ -Wall  -Wunused-variable   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/File.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/File.o File.cpp
    mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows
    rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o.d"
    g++ -Wall  -Wunused-variable   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o main.cpp
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows
    g++ -o dist/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/test build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/File.o build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o ../../../../../cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libgslip.a
    build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/main.o:/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/Test/Test/Common.h:8: multiple definition of `testout'
    build/Debug/Cygwin64-Windows/File.o:/c/home/skidmarks/Projects/Test/Test/Common.h:8: first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Every translation unit where you include `common.h` gets an `ofstream testout;` declaration. That's multiple definitions of the same object with external linkage.

Comment: My 'real' question was how to use a ofstream object across multiple translation units. Your redirect allowed me to rethink the issue (thanks) and to insert "extern ofstream testout" in Common.h and "ofstream testout" in main.cpp which solved my problem. I think that the title should be changed and the 'duplicate' answer referenced for background. But I think that this is a different question. Boy, do I feel dumb!

Comment: You can just ask a followup if the question isn't too broad. The immediate issue is fixed however. I think the duplicate fits.